# Positive symmetric matrix equals semi-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $A\geq 0$ does it mean that $A$ is semi-definite?

Comment: Yes. Semidefinite means positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you! Is it perhaps specifically positive semi-definite? Or not enough data to derive such a result?

Comment: When you write $A\ge0$, I suppose you mean that $A$ is positive semidefinite, unless you are talking about entrywise positivity.

Comment: The context behind is on page 10 chapter 3.3 Quadratic functions revisited of http://www.princeton.edu/~aaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf . I know that f can be proven convex if A is symmetric positive semi-definite but it just says that A≥0 , do you think the author supposes A as positive semidefinite?

Comment: Yes, the author means that $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Great thank you for your clarification!